# How you write these lines in Intel syntax?

Tags: assembly

How do you translate these lines from Linux assembly to Intel assembly?

```
pushl   cb_queue
pushl   %eax
popl    (%eax)

jg  .FOR_end0
.FOR_end0:

sete    (%esp)

pushl   $.rte_isqrt
.rte_isqrt:
.string "isqrt returns no value"
```

Comment: "Linux assembly" (??) Assembly has nothing to do with the OS - it's the type of your processor. I assume that by "Intel assembly" you mean x86? Please clarify.

Comment: Intel has been using many different architectures, not only x86, so "Intel assembly" doesn't mean anything. You should explicitly tag it with x86 AT&T syntax and Intel syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running [intel2gas](http://www.niksula.hut.fi/~mtiihone/intel2gas/) -g (the switch reverses the direction of translation) produces:

```
push    dword [cb_queue]
push    eax
pop     dword [eax]

jg  .FOR_end0
.FOR_end0: 

sete    [esp]

push    dword .rte_isqrt
.rte_isqrt: 
db      'isqrt returns no value'
```

(It's normally called AT&T syntax, not Linux assembly.)